# Google Maps API not displaying map tiles in IE11

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, internet-explorer-11

I'm experiencing an issue which only seems to occur in IE11. I have been used Browserstack to test this issue.

Either in desktop, or full screen mode the Google map on my contact page here will not be displayed. I cannot see any issues in the console and it loads fine in the previous version of IE. Contact page: http://ryanfitton.co.uk/contact/

I've also put up a very simple demo which uses the same code here: http://ryanfitton.com.

HTML:

```
<html>
    <style type="text/css">
        #map {
            padding:0!important; /*Remove Jumbotron padding. Added important for IE8*/
        }

        #map-canvas {
            height:500px;
            position:relative;
            z-index:1;
        }
    </style>

    <body>
        <div id="map">
            <div id="map-canvas"></div>
        </div>
    </body>

    <script src="maps.js"></script>
</html>
```

Maps JS:

```
function initialize() {
  //Map Custom Styles
  var styles = [
    //Start to display all features
    {
      featureType: "all",
      elementType: "all",
      stylers: [
        { saturation: -25 }, { visibility: "on" }
      ]
    },
    //Turn off individual features
    //Turn off Points of Interest (POI). E.g. Other businesses
    {
      featureType: "poi",
      stylers: [
        { visibility: "off" }
      ]
    },
    //Turn off Transit. E.g. Train stations and Bus stops
    {
      featureType: "transit",
      stylers: [
        { visibility: "off" }
      ]
    }
  ];

  //Map Styled options
  var styledMapOptions = {
    name: "Greyscale"
  };

  //Set to a variable
  var mapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, styledMapOptions);

  //Set Map options
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 10,                                               //Default Zoom level
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(53.6837636,-1.8310225),   //The default center of the map
    disableDefaultUI: true,                                 //Show default UI? True or False
    streetViewControl: false,                               //Show streetview controls? True or False
    scrollwheel: false,                                     //Allow scrolling of map with mouse scroll wheel? True or False
    draggable: false,                                       //Allow map to be draggable? True or False

    panControl: true,                                       //Show Pan controls? True of False
    panControlOptions: {                                    //Pan contol options
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
    },

    zoomControl: true,                                      //Allow zoom controls - Especially on mobile? True or False
    disableDoubleClickZoom: true,                           //Disable Double click zoom
    zoomControlOptions: {                                   //Zoom control options
      style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
    },

    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'Greyscale']
    },

    mapTypeId: 'Greyscale'
  };

  //Load map and insert into #map-canvas
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  //Set Map Type
  map.mapTypes.set('Greyscale', mapType);

  //Map Marker Options
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(53.6844873,-1.5032883), //Comment out line to not display an icon
    map: map,
    title:"Ryan Fitton"
  });

  //Force Map Data to stay in center when resizing window
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', initialize);
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
}


function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&' + 'callback=initialize';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryanfitton/o2za2Lu0/)

Comment: And a JSFiddle here: [http://jsfiddle.net/ryanfitton/o2za2Lu0/](http://jsfiddle.net/ryanfitton/o2za2Lu0/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code appears to work properly in Internet Explorer 11. The Fiddle was also not working in Chrome, which suggested the problem wasn't with a particular browser, but with either the fiddle configuration, the code itself, or the library (very unlikely).

Your code was set to execute `onLoad` per the jsfiddle configuration. The problem though is that when your code is executed, all it does is bind a handler to the `onload` event, which *already* happened by that time. By merely changing the jsfiddle configuration to run *unwrapped in <head>*, the issue is resolved.

http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/o2za2Lu0/8/

The website itself appears to work for me *as-is* without needing anything further:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Strange, I'll have another look at it as it did seem fine in chrome for me, just in IE I had issues. Cheers though.